# SubVersioning a Flash, jQuery, PHP Project

Tags: php, jquery, flash, actionscript-3, svn

I am building a Flash, jQuery, and PHP based project which I would like to subversion from the get go. I have experience using Dreamweaver CS5's sub versioning capabilities. So, as far as the PHP and jQuery (the non-flash portion) goes, I'm pretty comfortable.

However, I would like some recommendations on how to subversion the Flash portion. I know Flash Builder has SVN capabilities, however, the flash portion isn't going to function as and RIA, but more, if you will, like a game. As far as my experience with Flash goes, this type of project will work best if done in Flash Professional. Here are the options, as I see them:

1. find an extension for Flash Professional which will enable SVN. Is there one???
2. create a "Flash Professional Project" in Flash Builder, built it in Flash Professional, and subversion with Flash Builder.
3. place my project within a defined site in Dreamweaver, and subversion from Dreamweaver.

I would like to avoid something like Tortoise SVN, as I have had more difficulty with that than I am up for for now. :)

Does anyone have any suggestions, or pointers as to how I can handle this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: 1) Spend some time learning tortoiseSVN. There is a learning curve, but well worth it. 2) Never put your actionscript files inside your web accessible project directory. 3) Create a new trunk for flash/flex based projects(I call my trunk flash) 4) Only publish swf files to your web accessible directorys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, any SVN client can handle any kind of file - you don't have to have an extension built into each piece of software you're using. The best way to do this is to put all of your project files into a folder somewhere and then using whatever SVN client you want just add that whole folder to your repo. Does that make sense? The front-end that you're using is more or less irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I actually sorta felt that sink in as I was typing up my initial question. I was just trying to see what was a best practice. Also, speaking of best practices, when is the best time to commit an update to the repository: at the end of the day, when a particular phase of the project is completed (such as, say, the initial directory structure is created), or every time a particular file is updated? Are there best practices when commenting on a file that is being checked in? Sorry for the crash list of questions.

Comment: If only more developers asked such questions! :) Best time to check in is something you want to coordinate with your team if you have one. If not, I'd say a good rule of thumb is to check in every time you have added/changed a feature and the whole thing works. Leave detailed notes explaining what you changed. Then you can always roll back to a given state and know what you're getting.

Comment: @Myk you should be committing at least everyday. You should have your own branch so that your commits will not effect anyone else. Once you are ready to push your code then you need merge code into a staging branch from your branch. Once the staging branch is verified working and testing complete. Then it should be pushed to the trunk and of course to production from there.

Comment: Ok, great, then I guess I was pretty much on track. Myk, The_asMan, you guys are awesome! Thanks again! Points for you both!!!

Comment: @The_asMan you're not wrong, but if it's a one-person operation without a lot of SVN experience sometimes you can afford to be a bit more pragmatic. If the Original Poster is the only one working on it and just wants a bit of guidance as to how to use SVN for this project, breaking it out into branches etc won't hurt but might be overkill and may be a bit more complicated than what he's used to dealing with. But yes, you're right - that's the "right" way to do it. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are saying about TortoiseSVN, but since you are using different IDE's I would recommend you to use TortoiseSVN as the uniform interface to SVN. And IMO, TortoiseSVN is simple and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Man up and use the command line ;). Why SVN? Yes, I personally prefer it but there are other great alternatives, have a think about GIT, Mercurial and others too. Mercurial/Git have massive benefits for single developer projects. The flash file will be versioned just like everything else in there. Remember to set your ignore files appropriately to cut out all the os specific poop.

Soon as you get yourself a good versioning repository set up, it doesn't really matter what client you use. I like the one bundled with netbeans / versions or the cli.